# What is a good synonym for "sounds good"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Is there a good, versatile substitute for "sounds good"? "OK" isn't as positive. "It would be my pleasure" is too positive. "Yes" doesn't quite work. "Okey dokey" is too silly.

Comment: "Groovy" will get you odd looks now days. There are plenty other slang terms, but likely usage is likely localized. I think "cool" still works generally.

Comment: You'll likely want something different based on what exactly you're trying to mean. Do you mean "I accept", "I'll comply", "Doesn't bother me", "That sounds like a good idea", "That's awesome/cool" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually plenty of these. "Sure thing," "Of course," "All right," "That's fine," etc.

Each has a slightly nuanced difference, but the above are certainly more positive than a simple "OK" or "Yes" and less so than "It would be my pleasure."

Answer (score 3):

**10-4**

**good deal**

**alright**

**fine by me**

These are only a few examples of the many options available.  What feels most appropriate will vary depending on the context and personal preference.